# What is the expression for stating that it isn't for us to say something?

Tags: phrase-requests

I often use and here an expression that goes something along the lines of "who is it for us to say that ..."

But it looks like I must have picked it up wrong, because that is definitely not correct English.

Doing a Google search with my phrase only gives [one result](https://www.powder.com/salt/from-skiing-to-politics/):

> We know fundamentally that not everyone can live in Jackson. It’s physically and virtually impossible. But, at the same time, who is it for us to say who should and shouldn’t live here?

Can someone tell me what the actual expression is?

**Edit**: I think it might be "who are we to say that ...", but I do still recall a form that has "is it for us to say" in it.

Comment: https://youtu.be/b7xyAM7uF6I

Comment: So this is just a question for how the idea is specifically worded? eg "It's not for me to say." or "Who am I to say?" or some very slight variation? Must it also be 'we' rather than 'I'?

Comment: @Mitch Yes, but I remember the variation I had in mind having "is it for us" in it (but I could be mistaken).

Comment: *Now , when half of the people in that country are refugees , **is it for us to say** we continue to give military aid and impose on these people further death and starvation and human misery?* https://www.google.com/search?q=%22it%20for%20us%20to%20say%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1945,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en

Comment: ***Nor is it for us to say that** , in respect of union shop agreements , the provisions of the National Labor Relations Act are preferable to the provisions of the Railway Labor Act , or vice versa.*  https://books.google.it/books?id=zUxOAQAAIAAJ&q=%22it+for+us+to+say%22&dq=%22it+for+us+to+say%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJ29fM6Mb3AhXRRfEDHRq3BlMQ6AF6BAgJEAM

Comment: @user66974 your comments should be couched as an answer, should they not?

Comment: One expression may draw on the idiom of "knowing one's place": "It's not our place to say X." See [this Ngram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not+my+place+to%2C+not+your+place+to%2C+not+our+place+to%2C+not+his+place+to%2C+not+her+place+to%2C+not+their+place+to&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnot%20my%20place%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnot%20your%20place%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnot%20our%20place%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnot%20his%20place%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnot%20her%20place%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnot%20their%20place%20to%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: This is an expression, not an idiom, so you don't need to worry over the exact wording. There are several ways to express the idea. There's no best one. Just use what you know.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever its formulation, it's a common expression. Is it for us to say . . .?  Nor is it for us to say . . .

These are the results from Google NGram "not for * to say"

> not for me to say

> not for us to say

> not for him to say

> not for you to say

> not for them to say

> not for man to say

> not for her to say

> not for me to say

> not for courts to say

> not for anyone to say